# Multiple windows in Tkinter?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I am new to programming, and I am having trouble finding a tutorial that teaches how to create a GUI that uses multiple windows. For example, If a user clicks a "lookup" button, a window pops up with the search results. How do I accomplish this? Is this possible within Tkinter?
Any suggestions/ references to sources would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Clarification--I am not concerned with retrieving info/ populating the window just yet... I only need to know how to get the secondary window to appear upon command/ be able to place widgets on said window.

Comment: Instead of clarifying in the comment section, you can simply edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create your first window, you create an instance of the `Tk` class. All other windows are instances of `Toplevel`.

```py
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Add another window", command = self.newWindow)
        b1.pack(side="top", padx=40, pady=40)
        self.count = 0

    def newWindow(self):
        self.count += 1
        window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        label = tk.Label(window, text="This is window #%s" % self.count)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=40, pady=40);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        # b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Add another window", command = self.newWindow)
        self.count = 0
        self.canvas1 = Canvas(self, width=500, height=500)
        b1 = tk.Button(self.canvas1, text="Add another window", command = self.create_new_window)
        # b1.pack(side="top", padx=40, pady=40)
        self.canvas1.pack(side="top")
        b1.pack(side="top", padx=250, pady=240)


    def create_new_window(self):
        self.window1 = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.window1.geometry("+160+300")
        self.canvas1 = Canvas(self.window1, width=50, height=500)
        # label = tk.Label(self.window1, text="This is window #%s" % self.count)
        self.canvas1.pack(side="top", fill="both")

    def create_new_window2(self):
        self.window2 = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.canvas2 = Canvas(self.window2, width=500, height=500)
        # label = tk.Label(self.window2, text="This is window #%s" % self.count)
        self.canvas2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=40, pady=40)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("+300+300")
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```