# What is the best way to display multiple windows in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a Beauty salon management system.
The application consists of a login page the redirects users either to an admin panel or user panel.
so Far, I created my screens as classes.
The admin panel and user panel take a root parameter.

def main(self, root):
...

In the login page, I created a Function that destroys all widgets in the window.

If the user enters correct credentials, all widgets get destroyed and the one of the two panel classes are called and passed the Tk() instance of the Login page.

Is this a Good method?

Comment: Asking for a “best” will likely result in opinions, and opinionated questions are off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: One way is to call `<tk.Tk>.withdraw()` to hide the window and `<tk.Tk>.deiconify()` to show the window.

Comment: Your question was answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342764/multiple-windows-in-tkinter